# Split the array and put it on IF statement each of array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Im not good on jQuery so please pardon me. I want something to split the array in **IF statement** make a condition on each value in array.

This is my HTML

```
<table>
 <tr class="odd">
  <td><a href="q">q</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="even">
  <td><a href="q">r</a></td>
  <td><a href="z">z</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to make it like this

```
   <table>
     <tr class="odd">
      <td><a href="q">q</a><a href="q">r</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="even">
      <td><a href="q">r</a></td>
      <td><a href="z">z</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

so far this is what Ive done

```
var x = [];
$("table tr.odd a").each(function(){
  var q = $(this).attr("href");
  var e = $(this).parent().html();
  $("table tr.even a").each(function(){
    var w = $(this).attr("href");
    x.push(w);
  });
  if(q == x){
    //I dont know what to do here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few improvements that need to be done.

- Comparing string with an array is wrong
- When the idea is to append, then why to build an array, simply append within the loop

You can try following

```
$("table tr.odd a").each(function() {
    var that = this;
    var q = $(this).attr("href");
    var e = $(this).parent().html();
    $("table tr.even a").each(function() {
        var w = $(this).attr("href");
        if (q == w) {
            $(this).clone().insertAfter($(that));
        }
    });
});
```

For reference - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xdQlgoU6XFQZrDkvnKEQ?p=preview)

Comment: Tnx it helps a lot hehehe

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization - Welcome. I have added some improvements notes as well. Please see whether it helps!